# installation error in sklearn for python3

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python3

When I run the command  `sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn`

I receive a strange error.

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hrwadcyq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn
Storing debug log for failure in /home/donbeo/.pip/pip.log
```

here the link with the log file. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3FIuCA5bZUaUC1pd21MTUFxWkU/edit?usp=sharing

I have not any idea of how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2988) with the pre-compiled Cython C files (compatibility with Python 3.4.0) with the pypi version.

To properly install `scikit-learn`, use the git repo instead (tested ok on 14.04):

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

Comment: numpy and scipy are already installed. I am able to use sklearn on python2 so I think that also the C/C++ compiler is installed

Comment: Are you running 12.04 or 13.10? (or 14.04)

Comment: I am using a fresh installation of 14.04

Comment: ok, gimme 10m to boot my VM and check what could be missing

Comment: I've updated my anwser, the pypî version is not compatible with python3.4, use the git version instead.

Comment: it means that they have to update the pypy version?

Comment: Exactly, only a new upload from trunk will solve the compatibility issue

Comment: ok in this way will I still obtain automatic update and stuff like that?

Comment: No it won't work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710947/pip-pulling-updates-from-remote-git-repository.

Comment: ok I it is working. so I have to update it manually using the same command that I used to install it?

Comment: Exactly , no need to uninstall